# Is there a graphical tool to conveniently view git stash contents?

Tags: windows, git, user-interface, git-stash

Is there a GUI-based alternative to the command `git stash show -p stash@{0}` (preferably in conjunction with TortoiseGit, or WinMerge)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're not required to use `git stash` in particular. As long there's something in it, you can browse `stash` just as if it was a regular branch. You simply need to pass `stash` as a branch name, whether you use TortoiseGit, tig, gitk or anything else.

Moreover, Git use the exact same parenthood mechanism to maintain the stash stack than for merged branches: specifying multiple "`parent`" entries in each commit object, first one referencing previous stash entry (just like when building an ordinary branch), the other one referencing the commit where at when you stashed your changes (just like a `merge` integration of an external branch into the main one).

Consequently, any graphical tool should directly display these relations.

Comment: Thanks. So, you suggest something like `git checkout sha-of-stash`, then a graphical `git diff` tool, like TortoiseGit's?

Comment: Went on and tried that. I checked out `stash@{0}`, then selected `diff` from the context menu in File Explorer. But I do not get the changed files in the files list.

Comment: OK, I think I found that. Instead of using the `Git diff...` selection in the context menu, use the `Diff with previous version` selection. By default the dialog opens with the changed files in the stash.

Comment: The stash stack is built out of the reflog. The individual stash objects resemble merge commits (well, *are* merge commits, since "merge commit" just means "commit with 2+ parents") but are not meant to be used *as* merges. `refs/stash` points to the work-tree commit; its two parents are the index commit and the commit that was `HEAD` when the stash was made. (If it's a `git stash -u` stash, its *third* parent holds the untracked files.)